# how to prevent or stop increasing the size of textarea in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to prevent or stop increasing the size of textarea in jQuery?

I make a demo in which user press only 8 enter and 700 character, but my logic fail when User first press 7 enter and then start writing text. It comes in next line and the size start increasing. I want to stop to increasing size of that div when user enter text. In other words, if the user types up to height it will not increase size and stop writing.

http://jsfiddle.net/4WKgQ/1/

```
$(function() {
    var enterCounter = 0;
    var charCounter = 0;
    $(".myDiv").keypress(function(event) {
        var text = $(".myDiv").text();
        if(text.length == 700) {
            alert("Too many characters");
            $(".myDiv").text($(this).text().substr(0, 700));
        };
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            enterCounter += 1;
        };
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && enterCounter >=8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        };
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: also fails when user copy-paste on it

Comment: yes exactly ..Can we stop this ?

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) plugin..

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for

```
if (text.length >= 700)
```

rather than

```
if (text.length == 700)
```

Because in copy/paste first case much likely will fail

And you can add `onContextMenu="return false;"` property to your div to avoid mouse right click copy/paste.

Additionally there's a chance for the user to drag and drop the text. That means `.keypress` is not gonna be enough.

Comment: can you make example in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Change the css

```
.notes {
    width: 369px;
    min-height: 152px;
    color: black;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow-x: hidden; //prevent auto scroll the width
    overflow-y: auto; // This will auto scroll when content grows
    height: 200px;  //Add some height
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4WKgQ/4/

Comment: @Naveen Sharma if you want to prevent users from entering the data then you should consider `letter-count` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following to css to prevent textarea height change-

```
.notes{ height:152px; overflow:auto;}
```

Also, change the event from keypress to keyup and change the condition as follows

```
if (text.length >= 700)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WKgQ/6/)

Comment: it size is increasing when you write text on div

Comment: You need to fix the height and width of .notes class and give overflow as auto to prevent height change. Also, the **keypress** event has to be changed to **keyup**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
    var enterCounter = 0;
    var charCounter = 0;
    var totalCharsLimit=70;
    $(".myDiv").on('keypress',function (event) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length >= totalCharsLimit) {
            //console.log("Too much characters");
            $(this).text(text.substr(0, totalCharsLimit));
        };
        if(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46) return true;
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            enterCounter += 1;
        };
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && enterCounter >= 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        };
    }).on('DOMSubtreeModified',function (event) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text.length >= totalCharsLimit) {
            console.log('Limit exceeds');
            return false;
        }                
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/yLww8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

*Problem #1 - Expanding height issue:*

Update your css to this:

```
.notes {
    width: 369px;
    height: 152px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: black;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius: 12px;
    resize: none;
}
```

Notice the fixed `height` and added `overflow`.

*Problem #2 - Copy-Paste Scenario:*

Just added this function to check for copy-paste scenario, by getting the text after a little timeout:

```
$(".myDiv").bind('paste', function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var text = elem.text();

        if (text.length >= 100) {
            alert("More than 100 characters, trimming...");
            elem.text(text.substr(0, 100));
        };
    }, 100);
});
```

Rest of your code is working fine. Just changed the condition to `text.length >= x`.

Check your fiddle again: **http://jsfiddle.net/4WKgQ/8/**

Hope that helps.

---

**Edit: (After Op's clarification of actual requirement)**

Ok, now that you have clarified your actual requirement which is just to prevent the user to continue typing when the end of box is reached. If am right then, you don't have to do all of that. Just keep checking the scrollheight of the box against the height. Once it exceeds the height, it means the user has reached the end. You can then take evasive action.

Here is the sample fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c2PKY/**

*HTML*:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="txt"></div>
```

*CSS*:

```
#txt {
    width: 400px; height: 100px;
    overflow-x: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: black; border: 1px solid gray;
    resize: none;
}
```

*JS*:

```
var high = $("#txt").height();

$("#txt").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var content = $(this).text(), 
        contentLength = content.length, 
        scrolled = $(this).get(0).scrollHeight;

    $("#note").text(scrolled + ' / ' + high);

    if (scrolled > high) {
        $("#note").text("Exceeded, trimming...");
        $(this).text(content.substr(0, contentLength - 2));
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can we stop user to writting the text when it is end of height

Comment: now that would be tricky! you would perhaps be better off with a textarea with rows and cols set.

Comment: @NaveenSharma I have added an example of how you could do that. Please see the edit in my answer above.